# Custom nbextension's files not exposed on JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I created a custom extension for Jupyter Notebook with pretty advanced GUI written in React. This is how the files are structured:

[image: files structure in the source code]

When I install and enable the extension for a local Jupyter Notebook, all those files are exposed on the localhost and are then accessible to use in the extension.

[image: files on the server in jupyter notebook]

When I try to install the same extension on JupyterHub (I am using The Littlest JupyterHub) however, only some of the files are exposed. It can be observed that only the files imported as AMD modules in `main.js` are mapped do the server. Fetching others result in 404 error. This results in the unability to use the extension at all.

[image: files on the server in Jupyter Hub]

Is there something that I am missing while installing the extension? I am using this command in JupyterHub's terminal:

```
sudo -E jupyter nbextension install connector-jupyter --py --sys-prefix
sudo -E jupyter nbextension enable connector-jupyter --py --sys-prefix
```

All of the files are properly copied to the `nbextensions` directory:

```sh
admin@tec-l-011630:~$ ls /opt/tljh/user/share/jupyter/nbextensions/mstr_jupyter
cells-creation.js    jupyter-kernel.js   mstr.ico            ui-iframe.css
global-override.css  main.js             override_style.css  utilities.js
iframe_style.css     MicroStrategy.yaml  package-lock.json
jupyter-cells.js     mstr-connector      python-code.js
```